# How to disable database connection / middleware in laravel 5

Tags: database, laravel-5

is there a way to disable Laravel 5 database connection / middleware so it would not need to find a database anymore?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by would not find? if you are not using DB and didn't configure the Database file, then its mean you are not using DB. what else you are trying to do ?

Comment: the project that was handed to me initially connects to a database. but now we're just relying on API calls to pull data as well as do authentication so no need for the laravel app to directly interface with a database. before they shutdown the now unused database server, i need to ensure that i have properly applied configuration changes so that the app do not connect to the database anymore.

Comment: you can pass null values or set empty configuration fields in DB File, it will not use DB, but it does not mean that it will not use DB, if anywhere your code having interaction with DB it will show you the error. better to disable routes which are not using any more and you are required to test step by step